# Where to specify UI views in a hierarchy of model objects?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, layers, separation-of-concerns

In a Flutter app I'm developing, I have a class hierarchy of model objects of a certain base class. To take a typical example, the abstract base class could be `Vehicle`. Then I have a (pretty much) parallel hierarchy of widget classes that show info about a particular subclass of `Vehicle`: `Car` objects are shown with `CarWidget`, `Truck`s with `TruckWidget`, etc. These widgets all inherit from the ABC `VehicleWidget`. This is because all of the widgets have some part in common, which is the part that corresponds to the base class `Vehicle`, but each subclass of `Vehicle` needs to show some specialized info as well.  (If you don't like inheritance with Flutter widgets, then replace "inheritance" with "composition", what follows still holds.)

My app's global state holds a `List<Vehicle>`, and for each vehicle in that list it needs to show the corresponding widget. In order to do this, the runtime type of the vehicle must be checked. The natural object-oriented approach that comes to mind is to use virtual methods: declare an abstract method `makeWidget()` in the `Vehicle` class, and then make each subclass select the appropriate widget subclass.

However, I don't like mixing UI with model.
I thought of using extensions to define the `makeWidget()` method in a separate file, but extensions in Dart can't define virtual methods, they're essentially syntactic sugar for a regular function call (i.e. with static type checking).
What I ended up doing is `switch`ing on the runtime type explicitly:

```dart
abstract class VehicleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static VehicleWidget of(Vehicle vehicle) {
    switch (vehicle.runtimeType) {
      case Car:
      // ...  
      case Truck:
      // ...
    }
  }
 
  // ...
}
```

```dart
// whenever I need to create the appropriate widget for a vehicle
VehicleWidget.of(vehicle)
```

Now the "UI logic" of selecting the appropriate widget is with UI code and separate from model code.

However, this has a big disadvantage.
The compiler won't be able to tell me if I've forgotten to implement the appropriate widget (and specify it as a `case` in the `switch`) when I create a new subclass of `Vehicle`. Even worse, if there are multiple such parallel widget hierarchies (for example, `VehicleCard` and `VehicleDetails`), I need to mantain one `switch` statement for each of those.

My question is: which of the two approaches is better (for which scenario)? Is there any advantage to separating the selection of the appropriate widget class from the model hierarchy, as I have done?

Answer (score 2):

> However, I don't like mixing UI with model.

Why not? I mean, what is the rational reason behind this decision? I blame Robert Martin :). You're basically saying it would solve your problem, but you're not going to do it.

*It is ok to mix UI with Business*, in this case. How to display this stuff is closely linked with its internal representation and semantics. It makes absolutely no sense to artificially separate something from an object that basically needs *everything* from that object to work.

Note, you don't need to include *details* of the UI in the objects. You can even create a small, specialized widget set for this. You don't need to specify colors, or how it is positioned, etc., which is the scenario certain people are trying to scare others with.

Note 2: I did create Android apps previously (not flutter) where objects could present themselves. I needed to write a small UI framework for this, because `Fragment`s were too heavy weight, stateful and of the wrong scope.

On a minor note, don't call it `makeWidget()`, call it `display()` for example. "The `Vehicle` `display`s itself" makes complete sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this is to factor the switch logic into an interface/set of classes and a dictionary lookup. The key is the type of the vehicle and the class instance is the value. Voila--no more switch.

As you point out, the compiler no longer tells you when you've forgotten to implement an instance for a particular type of vehicle. However, it's easy to write an automated test that does this for you.

This is one example of the more general concept (you mention) of preferring composition over inheritance. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839793/replace-switch-case-with-polymorphism) is a question that addresses why one might want to do this.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using dictionary lookup instead of a switch? The latter can also be tested, right?

Comment: @Anakhand Added a reference to an SO question with the "why."

Answer (score 0):

A language-specific solution, but a nice solution nonetheless: it seems that [Dart 3 is introducing pattern matching and other features](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-3-alpha-f1458fb9d232), so I could declare `Vehicle` as a `sealed class` for exhaustiveness checking and use pattern matching similar to before:

```dart
static VehicleWidget of(Vehicle vehicle) {
  switch (vehicle.runtimeType) {
    Car() => ...
    Truck() => ...
    ...
  }
}
```

By making `Vehicle` a `sealed class`, I'm telling the compiler that the hierarchy of subclasses of `Vehicle` is fixed and so it can check when I forget to handle a subclass of `Vehicle` in one of these patterns.